# I am working in JavaScript any suggestions on how to use dynamic tables with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller

I am using check boxes in dynamic table to display true and false value.

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: People here do not suggest anything , until you show some effort to elaborate your question

Comment: Please try something yourself atlest and if its not working or you are facing some issues then come up for help.

Answer (score 0):

Since  you are using javascript i suggest using datatables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

Also you can refer[checkbox](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) here